# Multiple watermarks on same page in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, watermark

I am adding watermark images to a document using the watermark package in LaTeX. I keep overwriting the first one when I add another. How do I avoid this?

Sorry, I am pretty new to this...

Thanks!

```
\usepackage{watermark}

\thiswatermark{
 %\centering
\put(200,-750){\transparent{0.2} \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]        {image1}}
}

\thiswatermark{
 %\centering
 \put(200,-250){\transparent{0.2} \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image2}}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

`\thiswatermark` defines the watermark for a particular page, so, the second one overwrites the first, but you can declare several images on same `\thiswatermark` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{watermark}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\thiswatermark{
 %\centering
\put(100,-500){\transparent{0.2} \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}
\put(200,-250){\transparent{0.2} \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
}

Some letters
\end{document}
```